# How to handle the load spikes and queue the requests?

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Is there a configuration in Kubernetes in which I can specify minimum number of requests to be queued before a new instance gets spawned?

This is the context: We have got powerful high CPU machines set for our use case and every request levies a high amount of load on the server. Everything works perfect until we reach the specific number say... 300 requests with a ramp-up time of 100 milliseconds. And from that point we are receiving Connection refused error for some time and then the server starts to handle them once a new machine is spawned.  What is the best way to handle the load spikes? I am looking for something like "Pending latency" config in the app engine. My application is deployed on Google compute engine and orchestrated by Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readinessProbe` (see [container probes](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pod-states/#container-probes)) to indicate the container is ready to service requests, and use [`HorizontalPodAutoscaler`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/horizontal-pod-autoscaling/) to automatically scale your apps up/down based on observed CPU utilization. Hope this helps.

Comment: If I’d like to start sending traffic to a pod only when a probe succeeds, I would specify a ReadinessProbe. What if the probe failed and the other existing pod is not in a condition to handle any more requests? There is the place where some queuing must play its role to handle all the requests.